# So if image maps and slicing are out, what is in?

Tags: html, css

Googling image maps and slices clearly shows that they are no longer desirable tools to use.  Given that, what is the best way to approach making a complex shape clickable?

I've done some work with multiple images and using the z-index to change appearance but for a more complex image (that is more suited to a polygon shaped image map) is there an agreed upon best approach?

Answer (score 1):

I don't really see anything wrong with image maps, as such. [It's still in HTML5](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/embedded-content-0.html#image-maps-0). The biggest downside is that you need a, well, image, which may not always be what you want.

### SVG

[Using inline SVG](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/svg/a-element.html) seems to be the only alternative way to create complex *clickable* elements. [Browser support is decent](http://caniuse.com/#feat=svg-html5), but not universal.

Here's an example of a clickable star shape, I created this SVG with Inkscape, saved it as "plain SVG", removed some meta-data stuff, and added the `<a>` tag.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<body>
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">

</svg>

<svg
   xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/"
   xmlns:cc="http://creativecommons.org/ns#"
   xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"
   xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
   xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
   version="1.1"
   width="744.09448"
   height="1052.3622"
   id="svg2">
  <defs
     id="defs4" />
<!-- Added to inkscape file -->
<a xlink:href="http://example.com">

  <g
     id="layer1">
    <path
       d="m 214.28571,506.6479 -48.81229,-77.46894 -91.489505,-3.70793 58.593515,-70.36247 -24.74537,-88.1575 85.02508,33.98254 76.  +19603,-50.7764 -6.04513,91.36484 71.8371,56.77595 -88.76117,22.48403 z"
       id="path2985"
       style="fill:#000000;fill-opacity:1;stroke:#000000;stroke-width:1;stroke-linecap:round;stroke-linejoin:round;stroke-miterlimit:+4;stroke-opacity:1;stroke-dasharray:none" />
  </g>
</a>
</svg>

</body>
```

[You can also do more complex scripting](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/script.html)

A useful libraries: [svg.js](http://www.svgjs.com/), [Raphaël](http://raphaeljs.com/) (top search results, not an endorsement).

### CSS

CSS has traditionally had *very* limited support for complex shapes. And with 'complex shape' I mean anything that isn't a rectangle. Recently, you can do a bit more, although it's still not very flexible.

- Use a large `border-radius` to create roundish-shapes
- (ab)use borders to create triangles
- Use [CSS3 transforms](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform)

This may actually be enough for some usage, an advantage over SVG is that it's easier to create these shapes. But creating truly complex shapes with CSS is almost impossible. CSS was never really designed for this.

### Canvas

For completions sake, I also looked at the `<cancas>` element, which allows creation of complex shapes, but I haven't found a method to make only the shapes clickable.

Comment: SVG does seem to be the way to go.

Comment: Thank you for this detailed response!  I will take a look at SVG.